# how to get values from bootstrap timepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to get the value of the `bootstrap time-picker` on my `input` tag.  Once i get that value, the value goes to the database, after form is submitted.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label" >Start Session Time:</label>
  <div class=" date show-timer input-width input-group" id="datetimepicker1" >
      <input placeholder="HH:MM PM" name="start_session_time"  id="timepicker1" type="text" style="height:30px; font-size:14px" class="form-control input-sm" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
   </div>       
</div>
```

```js
$('.show-timer').click(function () {    
    var id = this.id;

    $('#' + id).datetimepicker({
        format: 'LT'
    });

    var time = $("#" + id).find("input").val();
});
```

NOTE: `id="timepicker1"` is not the only `input` id.  In other words, I have up to 10 ids. Also, so far, I can `alert(time)` and it does `alert` the value, but it doesn't add the value to the `input`

Thanks,

Comment: Which timepicker is this? There is a dozen for bootstrap.

Comment: @meskobalazs thanks for your comment.  I am using this one here: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: I think you might need something else to pass the value to the input tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to figure out what you are looking for. So at document ready I create the datetimepicker for each element. On dp.change event I alert a message containing both the datetimepicker and the corresponding input field value. As you can see they are the same:

```js
$(function () {
  $('[id^="datetimepicker"]').datetimepicker({
    format: 'LT'
  });
  $('.show-timer').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    var time = $("#" + this.id).data('date');
    if (time !== undefined) {
      var inputValue = $('#' + this.id).find('input').val();
      alert('datetimepicker value: ' + time + ' inputValue: ' + inputValue);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css"
          rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/e8bddc60e73c1ec2475f827be36e1957af72e2ea/src/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>



<form role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Start Session Time:</label>

        <div class=" date show-timer input-width input-group" id="datetimepicker1">
            <input placeholder="HH:MM PM" name="start_session_time1" id="timepicker1" type="text"
                   style="height:30px; font-size:14px" class="form-control input-sm" value="">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Start Session Time:</label>

        <div class=" date show-timer input-width input-group" id="datetimepicker2">
            <input placeholder="HH:MM PM" name="start_session_time2" id="timepicker2" type="text"
                   style="height:30px; font-size:14px" class="form-control input-sm" value="">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Start Session Time:</label>

        <div class=" date show-timer input-width input-group" id="datetimepicker3">
            <input placeholder="HH:MM PM" name="start_session_time3" id="timepicker3" type="text"
                   style="height:30px; font-size:14px" class="form-control input-sm" value="">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-2">
            <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope this can help you.

Comment: Hey I will take a look to this code, but they are not the same id: `datetimepicker1` and `timepicker1`

Comment: thanks for the code.  The only issue is that when I submit my form and I try to `echo name="start_session_time" ` in the `php` side, the value is empty.  Any idea?

Comment: I mean when i try to post the value

Comment: I will double check that in a few mins, i been to focus on make the timepicker working that i totally forgot about the php side -_- damn

Comment: @ArielMaduro I updated the snippet. On your server side you should find the fields like: $name = $_POST['start_session_time1']; Let me know.

Comment: Got it, thank you very much. And, yes my phphad the wrong names.